# How to add fade effect to a following jQuery slide function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, fade

I have this slide function http://jsfiddle.net/g7LwM/1/

How can I add fade effect to it? So while it is sliding down it fades in and when it is sliding back up it fades out?

**Important:** I noticed that most answers use toggle transition, it is different from slide transition I have. Toggle and slide have different transitions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need animate :
http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/g7LwM/7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#trigger").click(function () {
        $("#test").animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'});
    }); 
})
```

You can add in duration too :

```
$("#test").animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'},'slow');
```

Comment: Yes it fades in and out, I don't know if you noticed but the sliding function changed, if you compare it to fiddle I provided you can see how they are different in sliding. Thank you for answer though ))

Comment: @IlyaKnaup How did it change ? the answer stil does exactly the same as your JSFiddle - but fades .... that is what you asked in the Question ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for making it confusing, in my example google logo slides from top to bottom, where as in your fiddle it gets displayed. Van you see what I mean? If you compare both fiddles and pay attention to how they slide you'll see what I mean. Sorry for being confusing.

Comment: Oh I think I noticed the difference, your example uses toggle where as my one uses slide, they have different transition effects, that was what I meant.

Comment: @IlyaKnaup it does "slide" the combination of height: toggle and the duration make the "slide"

Comment: It slides in a different way, just compare http://jsfiddle.net/g7LwM/1/ with http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/g7LwM/7/ and look carefully at the transition. First drops from top, where as second gets displayed.

Comment: @IlyaKnaup it does slide but the duration is 600ms - the default - if you increase the duration then the slide is more obvious -> http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/g7LwM/10

Comment: ;D ohh man I am soo sorry for being like this, I put them both here http://jsfiddle.net/g7LwM/12/ please pay attention to how they act. Can you see the difference now?

Comment: @IlyaKnaup i can see that yours slides, mine slides and fades .... thats what you asked for  ?? if its not then ignore my answer and update your question to provide and better explanation

Answer (score 3):

Use [jQuery's `.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#trigger").click(function() {
        $('#test').animate({
            opacity: 'toggle',
            height: 'toggle'
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7LwM/8/).

**Additional Resources:**

If you're interested, this site has some great tutorials that will help you familiarize yourself with jQuery's `.animate()`: http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-animation-tutorials/

Comment: Yes it fades in and out, I don't know if you noticed but the sliding function changed, if you compare it to fiddle I provided you can see how they are different in sliding. Thank you for answer though ))

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party but I got it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/g7LwM/9/

Same as others, use animate to do height and opacity, however I didn't realise you could toggle them - +1 to the others for that.

Comment: Yes it fades in and out, I don't know if you noticed but the sliding function changed, if you compare it to fiddle I provided you can see how they are different in sliding. Thank you for answer though ))

Answer (score 1):

Chaining functions is really handy, but when it comes to animation, its a bit annoying because it'll perform them in order.

To get fade and slide at the same time, use `animate()`.

```
 $('#element').animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, "slow", callback_function);       
         or
   The best thing you can do is to write your own animation for it, something in line with:

     var slideDuration = 1000;

        var slideInAnimation = {        
            opacity: 1,    
            height: 'toggle'
        }

        var slideOutAnimation = {       
            opacity: 0,    
            height: 'toggle'
        }

        $('#anotherDiv').hover(function() {
            $('#myDiv').css("opacity", "0").animate(slideInAnimation, slideDuration);
        }, function() {
            $('#myDiv').animate(slideOutAnimation, slideDuration);
        });

   more link:
    http://api.jquery.com/animate/        
    http://www.openstudio.fr/Animated-InnerFade-with-JQuery.html?lang=en
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is a efficient way.... but it works....!!

Here is the magic:

HTML code :

```
<div id="frame">


<img src="image.jpg" />


</div>
```

In CSS :

set `display:none` for both "#frame" and "img"....

In JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("img").fadeIn(2000);

    $("#frame").slideDown(1000);

});
```